# How to get file properties (Created and Modified) from files in a .NET ZipPackage?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, zip, package

I'm using the ZipPackage-class in .NET to read and write zip-files. But how do I get basic file properties from files within a zip-package? I'm specifically looking for the date-times Created and Modified. I would prefer to not depend on a external lib of course, but it may be unavoidable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used the ZipPackage class, so I can't comment on that. But using other libraries, this should be easily possible. E.g. using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples), the following snippet extracts information about all entries (files) of a zip archive:

List entries in a zip. List all the entries in a zip file:

```
  using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
  {
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
    {
      System.Console.WriteLine("{1,-22} {2,8} {3,5:F0}%   {4,8}  {5,3} {0}",
                               e.FileName,
                               e.LastModified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                               e.UncompressedSize,
                               e.CompressionRatio,
                               e.CompressedSize,
                               (e.UsesEncryption) ? "Y" : "N");
    }
  }
```

(Class `ZipEntry` has other properties such as CreationTime, AccessdTime, etc.).